# ¿Como puedo agregar la condición if usando Python para la manipulacion de archivos locales ? Algún ejemplo?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ocupo realizar condiciones, ya sea if o  Switch cases a un archivo local a traves del lenguaje Python.

Es decir, cargar dentro de mi programa la lectura de un archivo txt, csv, etc. Y al contenido del mismo declarar condiciones

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tu pregunta es muy amplia... depende del contenido (su formato), y que condiciones quieres filtrar. Te dejo un ejemplo de como obtener partes del contenido dependiendo de un formato:

Suponiendo que tienes un archivo test.txt (con palabras divididas por puntos "."):

```
rojo.verde.azul.amarillo
violeta.naranja.rojo.purpura
```

El siguiente código separa cada palabra y almacena en una lista, después revisa si cada elemento es "rojo", si es rojo imprime su posición:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as file_object:
    for line in file_object:
        lista_linea = line.split('.')
        print(lista_linea)
        # Ahora navegamos en cada elemento y comparamos el contenido
        for index, elemento in enumerate(lista_linea):
            if(elemento == "rojo"): #si el elemento es igual a "rojo"
                print("La línea contiene el color rojo en la posición: " + str(index))
```

Notas:

1) Tutorial para aprender a usar el bucle **for**:
http://www.mclibre.org/consultar/python/lecciones/python-for.html

2) Para acceder a cada elemento use un índice "index" que almacena la posición de la lista. Aquí te dejo un enlace que explica sobre el uso de **enumerate** https://micro.recursospython.com/recursos/la-funcion-enumerate.html

3) Este enlace te explica a detalle el uso de la **condicional if**:
http://www.mclibre.org/consultar/python/lecciones/python-if-else.html

Comment: Ya que tengo almacenados los valores en una lista, ¿Cómo es que realizo una búsqueda?, supongamos que quiero que aparezca un numero '2' o cualquier otro valor cada que encuentre la palabra 'rojo', utilizando un if.